# Where oh where has my friend's server gone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a tool that will monitor Minecraft servers and notify you when they come online?

How hard would it be to make such a tool? How would you check without using the Minecraft client?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for :  [Minecraft Server Status Checker](http://www.xboxmb.com/forum/52-programming/31864-minecraft-server-status-checker-using-kinks-snippet.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to write such an app, the base code that the accepted answer uses is [here](http://www.xboxmb.com/forum/52-programming/31664-%5Bvbulletin-net-c-%5D-check-minecraft-server-status-%5Bsnippet%5D.html).

Comment: wow I thought it would involve MC credential passing to the server but dam it really is so incredibly simple.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Minecraft server communicates via port 25565 - so check that port on your friend's server for activity perhaps?